# function of Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am not very versed in stochastic calculus and I need help with this. I have a stochastic variable describing noise in a physical system, $\phi(t)$, whose derivative is white and Gaussian, i.e. it fulfils
$$
\langle \dot{\phi}(t)\rangle = 0
$$
and
$$
\langle  \dot{\phi}(t) \dot{\phi}(t')\rangle = \Gamma \delta(t-t')
$$
where the brackets indicate an average over the noise realizations. I am trying to compute the following ensemble average
$$
\langle e^{i[\phi(t_1) + \phi(t_2)-\phi(t_3)-\phi(t_4)]}\rangle
$$
and since the noise is Gaussian I know it should only depend on $\Gamma$. However I have no idea how to approach this calculation. I have found online the identity
$$
\langle e^{i[\phi(t_1) + \phi(t_2)]}\rangle = e^{-\Gamma\vert t_1-t_2\vert}
$$
but I don't know how it is derived nor how I can generalize it to the average I need. Can anyone help me find out how to do it, or point me to a very introductory text on the issue where I can find some answers? Thank you very much!